# Nginx, map to variable part of uri

Tags: nginx

is it possible to map and put to variable the part of parsed usi

I have a few users, all of them have own location, and uri looks like

```
/%USER_NUMBER%/content
```

I would like to map like

```
map $uri $user {
      default          0;
      ~^/([0-9]+)/    $1;
}
```

I mean to put to variable $user the number (user_number) from uri.
at my listing its not working
Thank you

Comment: You can create a named capture for use later, but unfortunately you cannot use it to create `$user`.

Comment: Cold you explain, please? in my case I logging by LUA and I need this variable for understanding information about requests and volumes of users, I can not set variable in Locations because my lua_log settled in http {} for all servers and locations. I trying to use map because it is only one way to handle that LUA could not works with late binding :(